# Add Custom button caption to message box

Tags: c++, mfc, messagebox

I want to have two buttons 'Stop' and 'Continue' in my messagebox. Can we have custom buttons in messagebox?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? Cause [this](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/messagebox/article.php/c10873/MessageBox-with-Custom-Button-Captions.htm) is my first search result.

Comment: If Windows Vista is the minimum target you may consider `TaskDialog`

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with Windows Vista, the OS provides the [TaskDialog API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx) as a replacement of the simpler but limited `MessageBox()` function.

Specifically, the [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx) function allows you to define custom buttons with individual labels. There is an example on the linked MSDN page.

If you have to support OS versions older than Vista, there are [projects like this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15900/WebControls/) which emulate the TaskDialog functionality.